# Tool that will remove duplicate lines from a file?

Tags: macos, file, diff, osx-lion

Is there a mac file comparison tool that can detect duplicates within a file?  This is very close to what I'm looking for except it is for Windows: http://www.rlvision.com/dupli/about.asp.  Also, I need to compare duplicate content across two files.  If nothing else, I can just append file2 content to the bottom of file1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know of a GUI app to do it, but it's fairly easy at the terminal:

`cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort | uniq -d`

The `-d` will make it show only duplicate lines. If you just want the output without duplicates, just leave off the `-d`.